# How to pass mysql data into radio button and use it at another page

Tags: mysql

What i am trying to do here is that, firstly i am building a quiz platform using juz php and mysql, and i have a table with question id, qestion, option1, option2, option3,  option4 and answer, so i want to pass the questions and the options from mysql to radio button and use the inputed values at the result page

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Provide your relevant code that you've got yourself so far, so that we can see your effort and clearly explain your problem (what doesn't work with your code) so that we won't guess what is it really you want us to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it work for you

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.table').hide();
    });

    function next(number){
        $('.table').hide();
        $('#table'+number).fadeIn(100);
    }
</script>
```

With in body

```
<?php

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id");

        $i = 1;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    ?>
    <table id="table<?php echo $i; ?>" class="table">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="1" id="td01" valign="top" >
                 <?php echo $row['qestion']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="td1"  class="tdradio" valign="top">
                <input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $row['option1']; ?>">
            </td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="td2"  class="tdradio" valign="top">
            <input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $row['option2']; ?>">
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="td3"  valign="top">
            <input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $row['option3']; ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="td4"  valign="top">
            <input type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $row['option4']; ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="question">
                    <?php echo $i; $i++; ?>/<?php echo mysql_num_rows($query); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="next">
                <div class="next" onClick="next(<?php echo $i; ?>);"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Tanks for the response, but i av up to ten Questions in my DB can dat work?

Comment: Hi Jiire, next('RECORD_ID'); here RECORD_ID is table records id

Comment: Can you please help with the code cuz am a beginner i dont know much

Comment: Hello Jiire, Give me 20 min